# F# broken in VS build tools 2019 16.6.0

Tags: f#

After installing this version, nothing that touches F# will build, everything throws the same exception:

```
error FS0193: Could not load file or assembly System.Buffers, Version=4.0.3.0, blablabla..
```

Apparently it's nothing to do with what I'm building. Even trying to execute `let x = 3` in fsi.exe has the same problem.

Anyone else had this problem?

Comment: Downgraded to 16.5.5, as some guy said, "I'm too old for this sh!t"

Comment: Yeah, that also works. Though the workaround only takes 30 sec to do, just copy the `dll` files.

Comment: @Benjol lol, I have that feeling a lot these days.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is a known problem, see https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/9295.

While the next fix isn't out yet, you can resolve it by [manually copying the missing assemblies](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/9295#issuecomment-634912756). The exact list of missing assemblies is mentioned in [this comment](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/9295#issuecomment-634389237). The cause was explained by Kevin Ransom to be that the Setup for MSBuild didn't get the new dependencies for `fsc.exe`.

Note that FSI from within Visual Studio shouldn't have this issue, nor should building from within Visual Studio 2019. The way I understand it, only the MSBuild Tools are affected.

For posterity, in case the links go dead, the workaround in the Github issue is to just copy the dlls over:

```
copy "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\*.dll" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\FSharp"
```

Edit: the source path given above may not always be correct, depending on what versions of VS you've installed. Alternatively, try:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\**Professional**\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\**Enterprise**\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\**Community**\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\**Preview**\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies

If you only want to copy the minimal set that's needed, just copy only these files, that's the diff set:

```
System.Buffers.dll
System.Memory.dll
System.Numerics.Vectors.dll
System.Reflection.Metadata.dll
System.Resources.Extensions.dll
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll
System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll
```